# Rails Route - Adding Controller Method to Route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Using `Rails 3.2.18`, I am new and I am trying to add this controller to the routeing. I am not really sure how to do this since the pre-existing format is different than the tutorials I have read. I don't know where to add the controller method name so it would be that  `/devices/deviceTextSearch` points to `device_text_search` and the view could refer to it by `device_text_search_path`

route snippet snippet:

```
  resources :devices, :only => [:index, :show, :update] do
    member do
      put :backup
      put :refresh
    end
    collection do
      get :find
    end
```

controller snippet:

```
  # GET /devices/find
  def find
    device = current_domain.device.find_by_logical_name(params[:device_id].strip)

    respond_to do |format|
      if device.nil?
        flash[:notice] = "Device '#{params[:device_id]}' was not found"
        format.html { redirect_to devices_path }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to device_path(device) }
      end
    end
  end

  #GET /devices/deviceTextSearch
  def device_text_search
    if params[:q].nil?
      @device_text = []
    else
       @device_text = DeviceTextSearch.search params[:q]
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
get '/devices/device_text_search' => 'devices#devise_text_search', as: 'devi    se_text_search'
```

This gives the following route:

```
                     devise_text_search GET    /devices/device_text_search(.:format)                                  devices#devise_text_search
```